# recommend drupal form cache disable?

Tags: 7, forms, caching, performance

I have static page and form but in each load in devel show a lot of query (select and Insert) in cache_form table I see form_set_cache and operation but I think may disable cache_form completely is a good work, I disable it in settings.php and don't reduce performance. 
do you think is this a good idea to disable form cache completely?

Comment: Generally I think it's never a good idea to disable cache. If I was you I would just leave it alone - it won't hurt and it may help.

Comment: That's a bad idea.

Comment: why? by disabling it reduce query number and don't change performance, also don't big my database, cache_form table increase in time and heavy my database !!

Comment: I add APC to my site with load time in my site was about 600 ms, then I disable form cache with DrupalFakeCache and my time reduce under 200 ms